# Resource (resx) editor with push pull to git repository

Tags: c#, localization, resx, resource-editor

Do anyone have experience with a resource editor (resx files) which can be pull and pushed to a git repository (in our case a local server).
There are a lot of this kind of programs, for example Zeta has connection to TFS, however is there support for git? (Without using Visual studio)

Kind regards